# JMonkeyEngine : Collision detection on dynamically loaded models

Tags: java, opengl, jmonkeyengine

I am learning JME3 and I managed to create my own height map and modifying some of the example code, etc. Now, I created a very simple 4-wall roofless room with Blender, exported it as a Wavefront .Obj file and loaded it unto my scene (I attacked it to the `terrain` node.

Now, my `terrain` has a collision detection applied so the player can move and jump around, but it can also walk right through the walls of my model. All the examples I can find loads an already pre-built scene, and I'm still clueless as to why the player goes right through the loaded model?

Sorry for the big code, but I couldn't see how else I could do otherwise. The physics is applied at the section `/** 6. Add physics: */` :

```
public class Main extends SimpleApplication
        implements ActionListener {

    private BulletAppState bulletAppState;
    private RigidBodyControl landscape;
    private CharacterControl player;
    private Vector3f walkDirection = new Vector3f();
    private boolean left = false, right = false, up = false, down = false;
    private TerrainQuad terrain;
    private Material mat_terrain;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(true);
        settings.setResolution(1366, 768);
        settings.setFullscreen(true);

        Main app = new Main();
        app.setSettings(settings);
        app.setShowSettings(false);
        app.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        /** Set up Physics */
        bulletAppState = new BulletAppState();
        stateManager.attach(bulletAppState);
        //bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().enableDebug(assetManager);

        flyCam.setMoveSpeed(200);
        setUpKeys();

        /** 1. Create terrain material and load four textures into it. */
        mat_terrain = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Terrain/Terrain.j3md");

        /** 1.1) Add ALPHA map (for red-blue-green coded splat textures) */
        mat_terrain.setTexture("Alpha", assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/terrain/island_1_alpha1.png"));

        /** 1.2) Add GRASS texture into the red layer (Tex1). */
        Texture grass = assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/grass.jpg");
        grass.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        mat_terrain.setTexture("Tex1", grass);
        mat_terrain.setFloat("Tex1Scale", 64f);

        /** 1.3) Add DIRT texture into the green layer (Tex2) */
        Texture dirt = assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/rocks.jpg");
        dirt.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        mat_terrain.setTexture("Tex2", dirt);
        mat_terrain.setFloat("Tex2Scale", 32f);

        /** 1.4) Add ROAD texture into the blue layer (Tex3) */
        Texture rock = assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/dirt.jpg");
        rock.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        mat_terrain.setTexture("Tex3", rock);
        mat_terrain.setFloat("Tex3Scale", 128f);

        /** 2. Create the height map */
        AbstractHeightMap heightmap = null;
        Texture heightMapImage = assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/terrain/island_1.png");
        heightmap = new ImageBasedHeightMap(heightMapImage.getImage());
        heightmap.load();

        /** 3. We have prepared material and heightmap. 
         * Now we create the actual terrain:
         * 3.1) Create a TerrainQuad and name it "my terrain".
         * 3.2) A good value for terrain tiles is 64x64 -- so we supply 64+1=65.
         * 3.3) We prepared a heightmap of size 512x512 -- so we supply 512+1=513.
         * 3.4) As LOD step scale we supply Vector3f(1,1,1).
         * 3.5) We supply the prepared heightmap itself.
         */
        terrain = new TerrainQuad("my terrain", 65, 513, heightmap.getHeightMap());

        /** 4. We give the terrain its material, position & scale it, and attach it. */
        terrain.setMaterial(mat_terrain);
        terrain.setLocalTranslation(0, -170, 0);
        terrain.setLocalScale(2f, 1f, 2f);
        rootNode.attachChild(terrain);

        /** 4.5. Load some models */
        Spatial building = assetManager.loadModel("Models/building1.obj");
        Material mat_default = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/ShowNormals.j3md");
        building.setMaterial(mat_default);
        building.setLocalTranslation(90, 117, 90);
        building.setLocalScale(5f, 5f, 5f);
        terrain.attachChild(building);


        /** 4.6. Load Sky */
        rootNode.attachChild(SkyFactory.createSky(assetManager, "Textures/Sky/Bright/BrightSky.dds", false));

        /** 4.7. Load water */

        // we create a water processor
        SimpleWaterProcessor waterProcessor = new SimpleWaterProcessor(assetManager);
        waterProcessor.setReflectionScene(rootNode);

        // we set the water plane
        Vector3f waterLocation = new Vector3f(0, -58, 0);
        waterProcessor.setPlane(new Plane(Vector3f.UNIT_Y, waterLocation.dot(Vector3f.UNIT_Y)));
        viewPort.addProcessor(waterProcessor);

        // we set wave properties
        waterProcessor.setWaterDepth(50);         // transparency of water
        waterProcessor.setDistortionScale(0.05f); // strength of waves
        waterProcessor.setWaveSpeed(0.05f);       // speed of waves

        // we define the wave size by setting the size of the texture coordinates
        Quad quad = new Quad(1000, 1000);
        quad.scaleTextureCoordinates(new Vector2f(10f, 10f));

        // we create the water geometry from the quad
        Geometry water = new Geometry("water", quad);
        water.setLocalRotation(new Quaternion().fromAngleAxis(-FastMath.HALF_PI, Vector3f.UNIT_X));
        water.setLocalTranslation(-500, -58, 500);
        water.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.Receive);
        water.setMaterial(waterProcessor.getMaterial());
        rootNode.attachChild(water);

        /** 5. The LOD (level of detail) depends on were the camera is: */
        List<Camera> cameras = new ArrayList<Camera>();
        cameras.add(getCamera());
        TerrainLodControl control = new TerrainLodControl(terrain, cameras);
        terrain.addControl(control);

        /** 6. Add physics: */
        // We set up collision detection for the scene by creating a
        // compound collision shape and a static RigidBodyControl with mass zero.*/
        CollisionShape terrainShape = CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape(terrain);
        landscape = new RigidBodyControl(terrainShape, 0);
        terrain.addControl(landscape);
        terrain.addControl(new RigidBodyControl(CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape(building), 0));

        // We set up collision detection for the player by creating
        // a capsule collision shape and a CharacterControl.
        // The CharacterControl offers extra settings for
        // size, stepheight, jumping, falling, and gravity.
        // We also put the player in its starting position.
        CapsuleCollisionShape capsuleShape = new CapsuleCollisionShape(1.5f, 6f, 1);
        player = new CharacterControl(capsuleShape, 0.05f);
        player.setJumpSpeed(50);
        player.setFallSpeed(70);
        player.setGravity(100);
        player.setPhysicsLocation(new Vector3f(50, 100, 100));

        // We attach the scene and the player to the rootnode and the physics space,
        // to make them appear in the game world.
        bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(terrain);
        bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(player);


    }

    /** We over-write some navigational key mappings here, so we can
     * add physics-controlled walking and jumping: */
    private void setUpKeys() {
        inputManager.addMapping("Left", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_A));
        inputManager.addMapping("Right", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_D));
        inputManager.addMapping("Up", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_W));
        inputManager.addMapping("Down", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_S));
        inputManager.addMapping("Jump", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_SPACE));
        inputManager.addListener(this, "Left");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "Right");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "Up");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "Down");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "Jump");
    }

    /** These are our custom actions triggered by key presses.
         * We do not walk yet, we just keep track of the direction the user pressed. */
    public void onAction(String binding, boolean value, float tpf) {
        if (binding.equals("Left")) {
            if (value) {
                left = true;
            } else {
                left = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("Right")) {
            if (value) {
                right = true;
            } else {
                right = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("Up")) {
            if (value) {
                up = true;
            } else {
                up = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("Down")) {
            if (value) {
                down = true;
            } else {
                down = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("Jump")) {
            player.jump();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main event loop--walking happens here.
     * We check in which direction the player is walking by interpreting
     * the camera direction forward (camDir) and to the side (camLeft).
     * The setWalkDirection() command is what lets a physics-controlled player walk.
     * We also make sure here that the camera moves with player.
     */
    @Override
    public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
        Vector3f camDir = cam.getDirection().clone().multLocal(0.6f);
        Vector3f camLeft = cam.getLeft().clone().multLocal(0.4f);
        walkDirection.set(0, 0, 0);
        if (left) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft);
        }
        if (right) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft.negate());
        }
        if (up) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camDir);
        }
        if (down) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camDir.negate());
        }
        player.setWalkDirection(walkDirection);
        cam.setLocation(player.getPhysicsLocation());
    }
}
```

So, why isn't my model applied to the collision detection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer, [here](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:physics). The solution to the problem is this :

> 1. Create a CollisionShape. Create a PhysicsControl by supplying the
> 2. CollisionShape and mass. E.g. com.jme3.bullet.control.RigidBodyControl
> 3. Add the PhysicsControl to the Spatial. Add the PhysicsControl to the
> 4. physicsSpace object. Attach the Spatial to the rootNode, as usual.
> 5. (Optional) Implement the PhysicsCollisionListener interface to respond
>      to PhysicsCollisionEvents if desired.

Therefore, replace

```
terrain.attachChild(building);
```

by

```
rootNode.attachChild(building);
```

and adding

```
bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(building);
```